# Data Driven testing using Coded UI

Tags: coded-ui-tests

Is it possible to access more than 255 columns of Datasource (Excel) using Coded UI, currently I am using VSTS 2013 and found that Coded UI is not able to access more than 255 columns from the DataSource. Is there a way to overcome this limitation? I don't want to split my test case in two parts, also I have to use Excel as DataSource.

Comment: Why not just use a datatable as source and fill it with data from your excel?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/9668)

Comment: Can't use that or you can not allowed to use Database, as I have already created many cases using Excel and in addition to it, I have customized Excel (like binding it with same lookup value as in application, to have dropdowns for selection), Color Coding, Rules for dependent column values etc. Is there a way (lets say some plugin or extension or new version of Coded UI) which can eliminate this column size issue?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/9668)

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to include delimited fields within the Excel cells. I normally use CSV ("comma" separated values) for the data source file but the conversion to and from an Excel spreadsheet is easy. A simple example with pipe ( `|`) delimited field within the CSV would be:

```
FieldA,FB,SFC1|SFC2|SFC3,SFD-3,FieldE
AAone,BBtwo,CCthree|CCfour|CCfive,DDsix|DDseven|DDeight,FFnine
```

Here five CSV (Excell) cells are separated by commas. Two of them have pip delimited sub-fields. Giving nine fields in total.

To use the above fields you might do something like:

```
string[] SFC = TestContext.DataRow["SFC1|SFC2|SFC3"].ToString().Split('|');
string[] SFD = TestContext.DataRow["SFD-3"].ToString().Split('|');

string ValueOfFieldA = TestContext.DataRow["SFD-3"].ToString();
string ValueOfSFC2 = SFC[1];
string ValueOfSFD3 = SFD[3];
```

Using a field name like `SFC1|SFC2|SFC3` may be useful for documentation, but naming all the subfields may be excessive. Having a shorter field name such as `SFD-3` gives the hint that three fields are expected.

Note that the array indexing in `SFC[1]` and `SFD[3]` should probably be preceded by a check that the elements actually exist.

Comment: looks a good option to me, this way I can reduce the total number of columns so that they fall under 255.